# Website through AWS S3 Bucket returns a 404

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3, web-hosting

I'm trying to publish my static HTML, CSS, and JS website through AWS S3 bucket. However, I'm running into several issues. After purchasing my domain, I created an S3 bucket called 'drainleaf' and then following the AWS Youtube tutorial, I tried to publish my site.

However, I'm getting some errors. I uploaded my site folder in the 'Overview' tab of S3. Then, inside the properties tab, I added my index.html file. Lastly, i added bucket policy in Permissions Tab.

I'm getting a 404 not found error when i visit the domain. 
Below are the links to the screenshots for context:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsSii.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s6jN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alqFi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkmN7.png)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is for you to use your S3 bucket like this, you need to name the S3 bucket after the domain it will be used on.

So in your case it's a 404 because the bucket name of your domain does not exist.

2 solutions to resolve this:

- Create a new S3 bucket and give it the name of your domain name.
- Create a [CloudFront Distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) in front of your S3 bucket, if you do this you can get a free SSL via [ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) so you can serve your website over https.

Comment: I was able to get the site to publish. But now, its NOT reading the CSS files. 
I think it may have to do with the folder structure and how i have it set up in the code and S3 Buckets.
For example:
<link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="http://localhost:9000/DrainLeaf GAMES/CSS/css_template.css" />

This is how i have the css linked to my html files. But in the screenshot of my S3 Bucket 'Overview' Tab, I have uploaded the files directory without the parent folder: "DrainLeaf Games". And if i do upload the folder with all the files, S3 gives an error again. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that will do it, whichever tool you are using should be publishing without domain names